# Proving that f is analytic by Morera's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that " If *f* is continuous in a domain D⊂C and *f* is analytic in D∖γ 
where γ∈D is a smooth arc then *f* is analytic "

To solve this problem, I think I should use Morera's Theorem. But I can't complete the proof. Please help me.

Comment: Usually questions are better received if one includes what one has tried so far.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference